# How to make Alien Swarm dedicated server to automatically say announcements?

Tags: alien-swarm

What I want is to make my server to automatically print invitation text to every player when he connects my server. Or I want my server to say a message in fixed time interval. How do I do it?

Do I need to use SourceMod for this? If yes, how do I make it using SourceMod?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is needed to install SourceMod and [Advertisements plugin](http://forums.alliedmods.net/showthread.php?p=592536). It has all the documentation. Here is an example of advertisements.txt:

```
"Advertisements"
{
    "1"
    {
        "type"      "S"
        "text"      "Please download the latest addon maps: www.moddb.com/games/alien-swarm/addons/alien-swarm-mappack-12"
    "flags"     "z"
    }
}
```